# JFrame - adding KeyListener causes NullPointerException

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jframe

I couldn't find the answer anywhere. I have a JFrame that I'm adding a `KeyListener` to,  but it keeps throwing a `NullPointerException` when I do. I can create a new instance of it just fine:

```
KeyListener k = new GameKeyListener();
```

It throws no exceptions when I create an instance, but the exception happens when I add it to the JFrame. The code for GameKeyListener:

```
package garhoogin.main;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import static garhoogin.main.Main.*;

public class GameKeyListener implements KeyListener{

    public static boolean left = false;
    public static boolean right = false;

    public GameKeyListener(){};

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT && started) left = true;
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT && started) right = true;
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE && !started) started = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT && started) left = false;
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT && started) right = false;
    }

}
```

Can someone please help me? I don't know why this isn't working.

Comment: If it throws a NPE, then do some basic debugging. The error message will tell you the statement that causes the problem. So find the statement and figure out which variable is null and then fix the problem. Not sure how you expect us to help since we don't know the variable causing the problem. Note, the variables in your class should not be declared "static". I also have no ideas why you would be using a static import.

Comment: It said that the statement causing the problem was the actual addKeyListener part. From there, it stops showing any detail. I was working on my game code, and the Game class addKeyListener was the highest level error it gave me.

Comment: Post the [mcve] that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: *"It said that the statement causing the problem.."* Always copy/paste error and exception output!

Comment: I  think I fixed it. I tried adding the KeyListener before adding anything to the JFrame and I'm not getting this exception anymore.